# Absolute and Minimum on domain

Tags: calculus

Absolute maximum and minimum for $$f(x,y)=y\sqrt{x}−y^2−x+3y$$  on the domain $0≤x≤9, 0≤y≤8$

I was able to solve the absolute minimum but for some reason I cannot seem to get the absolute maximum for this function?

Comment: I did these steps and did not the answer. I got f(0, 0) which was incorrect

Comment: Perhaps show your work ... It's likely you've made a mistake differentiating.

Comment: I tried f(0, 3/2) as well but it did not work

Comment: Hopefully that makes it more clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First calculate the partial derivatives.

$f_x = \frac{y}{2\sqrt{x}} - 1$, and $f_y = \sqrt{x} - 2y + 3$

then solve this system of equations:

$\frac{y}{2\sqrt{x}} - 1 = 0$

$\sqrt{x} - 2y + 3 = 0$

from this we get that $y = 2, x = 1$ so we have a critical point at $(1, 2, 3)$. We know this is a maximum because, $f_{xx} = \frac{-y}{4x^{3/2}}$ and $f_{xx}(1, 2) = -1/2$ which is less than $0$.

Also here is a graph if you are curious

[graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/10bto.png)